# how to include the dynamic page in the template php?

Tags: php

I have 3 pages `template.php` and `page1.php` and `page2.php` , and a page1 and page2 menu in template, I want when I click on page1 in the template menu it includes the content of page1 in template and when i click on page2 it included contents of page 2.

**template.php**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>TEMPLATE</h1>
    <a href="page1.php">page1</a>
    <a href="page2.php">page2</a>

    <?php include($content); ?>
    
    <h1>TEMPLATE</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

**page1.php**

```
<h2>page 1</h2>
```

**page2.php**

```
<h2>page 2</h2>
```

Comment: make sure you use `<?php...?>` tags in every page you have

Comment: @Fafanellu Thanks for your answer, can you explain me more?

Comment: please post the whole code of your `php` scripts. So far, you have only `HTML` code in page1.php and page2.php

Comment: @Fafanellu yes, that's my problem, I don't know what I want to write in page1 and page 2, I just wrote <h1>page1</h1>

Comment: if they are `PHP` files, they should contain `PHP` tags : `<?php...?>`. Then just follow Nico's advice : use `include` in order to achieve what you want. You'll find a lot of ways to do so on Google, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

So in your example, it will be:

```php
<html>
  <head>
    <title>template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>TEMPLATE</h1>
    <a href="page1.php">page1</a>
    <a href="page2.php">page2</a>

    <?php echo $content; ?>
    
    <?php include('page1.php') ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can also use [require](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php). The difference is that if you use `require`, your code will fail if the file is not found. With include, the code still executes no matter what. So is up to you here.

Comment: thank you for your answer but when I click on page 1 it redirects me to page 1, it does not include content from page 1

Comment: Can you explain a little more what is in page1.php? Because if you only have html content, it should display that there.